# What are the pros and cons of using PfSense DNS Forwarder or Resolver?

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, resolve

I am looking for a clean set of pros and cons for two mutually exclusive DNS configurations for pfsense router: **Forwarder and Resolver**.

The configuration that I have in mind is a complex home-office setup with VPN to office, dial-in VPN and two internal network (VLANs) (Ipv4+Ipv6), one with access to corporate and one without.

There is a long list of DNS servers which I want to use for looking up non FQDN hostnames and usually I got this configured as search list in DHCP but I started to believe that this is likely to cause problems with clients which would have to lookup hosts, and maybe it would be faster to keep these cached on the router (extra points for Resolver in this case?)

Note: I am aware about the long https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/51x20p/dns_resolver_vs_dns_forwarder/ thread but that one is archived so having a clean response here would be a longer lasting way to document it.